# Save an image to disk without using all the ram

Tags: python, arrays, image

I work processing really big images of the likes of GIS and Astronomy images. I need to find a library preferably in python that allows me to append bits to an image and write it piece by piece to disk without having to have all the image in RAM at once.

**Edit:** 
Thanks to those who commented. I work with microscopy images. Mostly those that can be opened with [Openslide](https://openslide.org). Some of them are in this [list](https://docs.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/5.8.2/supported-formats.html). My goal is to have just one big file containing an image, a file that can be opened by other people instead of having a bunch of tiles.

But unless I have lots and lots of RAM (which I don't always have and people don't always have) I can't create images as big as the original and store them with things like PIL.image. I wish I could create an initial file, and then append to it the rest of the image as I create it.

Just like with GIS and AStronomy, microscopy has to create images based on the scans, and process them, so I was wondering if anyone knew a way to do this.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What format do you have in mind? and what/how do you want to append this? Anyway, the general method is by using memory mapping.

Comment: 'Chunking' can be used with GeoTiffs to deal with this issue. Read and write an image in chunks as opposed to dealing with the array as a whole. Hope this gives you a starting point.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that's totally possible. to use data, a computer copies it to RAM.
If you just want to append your data to your image, use PIL.Image

Comment: I think you're incorrect here. There are many ways to write an image without having to have the whole image in memory. For instance, there are ways to write an image row-by-row/chunk-by-chunk which do not require the entire image array to be in memory.

Comment: @tda that is exactly what I need